# How do I ignore local modifications without doing a checkin in svn?

Tags: svn

I need to know how to get svn to ignore local modifications without making a commit.  Here is a break down of why:

- I need to run an internal tool
- This tool uses a file which currently works in our build environment
- This tool does an svn status to look for any uncomitted changes and fails if it finds any
- I am trying to debug locally, but I need to make a small change to use my user ID instead of our build environment's headless user
- When I change the file to point to my local user, it shows up as modified when I run `svn status` and now the tool won't finish running since my svn workspace isn't clean

I don't want to check in any changes for this, since the changes I need to make are all local. I can't do an `svn propset svn:ignore <file> <dir>` since that would require a checkin to get it to ignore.

*Is there any way I can get svn to ignore my local changes and make svn status show up as clean **without doing a checkin**?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a "template" for this file and version that, then have users make a local (non-SVN) copy of the file for their local modifications.

[Straight from the FAQ](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit)